# SIGSEGV when calling JS_NewStringCopyN twice

Tags: c++, javascript-objects, seamonkey

I have been trying to use the Mozilla / SeaMonkey JavaScript library that ships with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, `mozjs185-1.0`, but am encountering a `SIGSEGV` when I try to call `JS_NewStringCopyN` twice to allocate two `JSString` objects from `char *` strings.

My sample code is as follows:

```
#include <js/jsapi.h>
#include <js/jscntxt.h>
#include <js/jscompartment.h>

size_t gStackChunkSize = 8192;

static void
my_ErrorReporter(JSContext *cx, const char *message, JSErrorReport *report)
{ }

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    JSRuntime *rt = JS_NewRuntime(256L * 1024L * 1024L);
    if (!rt)
       return -1;

    JSCompartment compartment(rt);
    JSContext *cx = JS_NewContext(rt, gStackChunkSize);
    if (!cx)
        return -2;
    JS_SetErrorReporter(cx, my_ErrorReporter);
    cx->compartment = &compartment;

    const char data[] = "PScript5.dll Version 5.2.2";
    const char data2[] = "Thom Parker";

    JSString *str = JS_NewStringCopyN(cx, data, sizeof(data));
    JSString *str2 = JS_NewStringCopyN(cx, data2, sizeof(data2));

    return 0;
}
```

Which I compile with:

```
g++ test.cpp -o mdntest -I/usr/include/nspr -lmozjs185-1.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lz -lnspr4  -lpthread
```

When I run `./mdntest` it generates a `SIGSEGV` and crashes.  Having debugged the 1.8.5 version of the Mozilla JavaScript library, I know that what is happening during the second call to `JS_NewStringCopyN` is that the garbage collector is called (`JS_gc`) and that somewhere it is trying to do a mark and sweep pass but is accessing some invalid memory, 30 levels deep in the back trace with a call to `js::gc::ArenaBitmap::markIfUnmarked`.

My theory is there is some undocumented thing I'm forgetting do do after calling the first `JS_NewStringCopyN`.  Any advice or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the record, although I have a solution below for the problem as stated, the issue I needed to solve was a bit more nuanced in terms of Memory Pool corruption in JavaScript, relating to a data structure submitted without a proper terminator element, causing JavaScript memory to be corrupted and the Garbage Collector to crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example code above, the issue I've found is that a `JSCompartment` must be manually initialized before use.

Thus, by adding:

```
compartment.init();
```

right after the construction of compartment in `JSCompartment compartment(rt);` the two `JS_NewStringCopyN` are called without error and the garbage collector `JS_gc` runs without error.  Why the `JSCompartment` doesn't call `JSCompartment::init()` in its constructor and why this isn't clearly documented is beyond me.